# How to make the popup box show up once the site is opened

Tags: html, css, popup

http://jsfiddle.net/f5K6u/2/

Hi guys. Any idea on how to make the popup box appear once the site is open. Currently the popup box will only open once clicked. Can this be possible that the box would open once the site is done loading.

```
<span class="box">
<span class="title">Title</span>
<span class="copy">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus</span>
```

Comment: Add `checked='true'` to the `<input>` element. The popup opens based on this like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5K6u/3/).

Comment: check for existance of a cookie, if it doesn't exist open the popup then set the cookie from within a windows.onload(){} function

Comment: Won't the animation not fire when using checked='true' on page load? I mean if its not important on initial load then NBD.

Comment: @TheHamstring: Very true. But if animation is required, OP can use JS/jQuery to set the `checked='true'` on page load like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5K6u/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the pop-up to appear on page load itself (instead of after clicking on the button), make the `<input>` as default selected on page load itself by adding `checked = 'true'` to the tag.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="linkie" class="popUpControl" checked='true'>
```

**Note:** The above doesn't show the animation/transition effect because it had no state transition. If you want the transition also to appear on page load, you have to initially leave the `input` as unchecked (like in your exisitng code) and then mark it as checked during page load using Javascript.

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('linkie').checked = true;
}
```

[**Demo without transition**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5K6u/3/) | [**Demo with transition**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5K6u/4/)

**Extra Information for Understanding:**

The below is the piece of CSS which triggers your box to appear.

```
.popUpControl:checked ~ label > .box {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) skew(0deg);
    -moz-transform:    scale(1) skew(0deg);
    -ms-transform:     scale(1) skew(0deg);
    -o-transform:      scale(1) skew(0deg);
}
```

The selector effectively indicates to the browser that when the element with `class='popUpControl` (`.popUpControl`) is checked (`:checked`) then the element with `class='box'` and has label as a parent should be made visible (using opacity). The scale, skew and opacity all together makes it get displayed whereas the `transition` set on the `.box` causes it to become visible in an animated/transitioned manner.